# How to send Empty Parameter to Server via Volly-Library in Multipart Request?

Tags: android, android-volley

i am Sending Multiple Data to Server Like Video,Image and Text In my case when i Upload a **All Data it will be Uploded** but , in My application some Data is not Mandatory So it will be Blank or NUll.
When i  send this kind of Request **(with null value or blank)** to Volly it is Giving Me Toast From Error Listner.
In Below code (AdvertiseImage2ImageBitmap) will be null and I am getting Toast From Error Listner
How to Resolve This. i am Searching from 2 Days.

```
private void uploadAdNewUser() {
    String[] parts = Duration.split("\\:"); // escape .
    Video_Min = parts[0];
    Video_Sec = parts[1];
    Utils.pdialogMk(AddAdvertisePublicity.this);
    VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConstants.MainUrl + AppConstants.AddAdvertise,
            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                        Utils.pdialog_dismissMk();
                        if (obj.getString(AppConstants.flag).equals("true")) {
                            Utils.ShowToast(obj.getString(AppConstants.message));
                            startActivity(new Intent(AddAdvertisePublicity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            //finish();
                        } else {
                            Utils.ShowToast(obj.getString(AppConstants.message));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Utils.pdialog_dismissMk();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {

        /*
        * If you want to add more parameters with the image
        * you can do it here
        * here we have only one parameter with the image
        * which is tags
        * */
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> KeyParams = new HashMap<>();
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.name, Name);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.address, Address);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.email_id, Email);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.birth_date, Dob);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.mobile_no, MobileNo);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.mob_imei, Imei1);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.mob_imei2, Imei2);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.age, Age);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.height, Height);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.chest, Chest);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.waist, Waist);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.weight, Weight);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.price, Ad_Price);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.sex, Gender);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.video_min, "00:" + Video_Min + ":00");
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.video_second, "00:00:" + Video_Sec);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.character, Character);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.interest, Interest);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.interest_notes, Interested_Notes);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.state, SelectedState);
            KeyParams.put(AppConstants.city, SelectedState);
            return KeyParams;
        }

        /*
        * Here we are passing image by renaming it with a unique name
        * */
        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            long AdImage1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long AdImage2 = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1;
            long VideoName = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3;
            params.put(AppConstants.advertise_image1, new DataPart(AdImage1 + ".png", getFileDataFromDrawable(AdvertiseImage1ImageBitmap)));
            params.put(AppConstants.advertise_image2, new DataPart(AdImage2 + ".jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(AdvertiseImage2ImageBitmap)));
            params.put(AppConstants.video, new DataPart(VideoName + ".mp4", Vidbuffer));
            return params;
        }
    };

    //adding the request to volley
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(volleyMultipartRequest);
    volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);
}
```

Comment: you mean **AdImage1** and **AdImage2** are not Mandatory ???

Comment: Please post Error Message .

Comment: com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: if this bitmap is null then how to handle this error :(

Comment: yes u can handle null bitmap. Two way 1. try catch, and 2. check with if clues

Comment: if (AdvertiseImage1ImageBitmap != null) {
            params.put(AppConstants.advertise_image1, new DataPart(AdImage1 + ".png", getFileDataFromDrawable(AdvertiseImage1ImageBitmap)));
        }
        if (AdvertiseImage2ImageBitmap != null) {
            params.put(AppConstants.advertise_image2, new DataPart(AdImage2 + ".jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(AdvertiseImage2ImageBitmap)));
        }
        if (Vidbuffer != null) {
            params.put(AppConstants.video, new DataPart(VideoName + ".mp4", Vidbuffer));
        }

Comment: yes let me do that

Comment: i have done this Thanks Sanjay for Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some changes to your getByteData() method. 
listed below.

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
        Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
        long AdImage1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long AdImage2 = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1;
        long VideoName = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3;
        if (AdvertiseImage1ImageBitmap != null) {
            params.put(AppConstants.advertise_image1, new DataPart(AdImage1 + ".png", getFileDataFromDrawable(AdvertiseImage1ImageBitmap)));
        }
        if (AdvertiseImage2ImageBitmap != null) {
            params.put(AppConstants.advertise_image2, new DataPart(AdImage2 + ".jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(AdvertiseImage2ImageBitmap)));
        }
        if (Vidbuffer != null) {
            params.put(AppConstants.video, new DataPart(VideoName + ".mp4", Vidbuffer));
        }
        return params;
    }
```